# Run the migrate and test is very slow with my database

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

When I run `manage.py test` or `manage.py migrate`, it takes about 10 minutes.

> ---
>
> Ran 154 tests in 6.427s
>
> OK (skipped=12) Preserving test database for alias 'default'...
>
> real  10m12.819s
>   user  7m51.232s
>   sys   0m31.632s

I Have approximately **200 models**, separated in approximately **35 apps**.
Each app has the **0001_initial** *file migration* and at most **4** others migration files

Someone has gone through something similar?
**Thanks**

Comment: you seem to be running your tests with the -k option, "Preserving test database for alias 'default'.." so the database is not being created.

Comment: For the tests, i am using the -k option.. my problem is when i need run the   migrate, because i have many databases **(400+)**.

Answer (score 0):

I think there have been some improvements in Django 1.9. See this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24743